# Не отправляться сообщения всем пользователям

Tags: python, discord.py

Проблема в том что бот отправляет сообщение только 5ти пользователям. Что мне делать

```
@bot.command()  # Рассылка message_all
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)  # права на команду
    async def message_all(ctx):
        #channel = bot.get_channel(876391511493836800)
        content = "Здравствуйте выжившие ! Это плановая проверка системы оповещения бота. Есле вас не затруднит отправте + в общий канал. С любовью EventBot \n Hello survivors! This is a routine check of the bot's alert system. If it does not bother you, send + to the general channel. Love EventBot"
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                await member.send(content)
                #await channel.send(f'Сообщения были отправлено этому пользователю : {str(member)} ')
                print("Отправил " + str(member))
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: ограничения по работе с api? что содержится в bot.guilds? то есть там, содержание переменной верное?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у пользователя заблочена личка для рандомов, есть решение:

```
    @bot.command()  # Рассылка message_all
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)  # права на команду
    async def message_all(ctx):
        #channel = bot.get_channel(876391511493836800)
        content = "Здравствуйте выжившие ! Это плановая проверка системы оповещения бота. Есле вас не затруднит отправте + в общий канал. С любовью EventBot \n Hello survivors! This is a routine check of the bot's alert system. If it does not bother you, send + to the general channel. Love EventBot"
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            for member in guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send(content)
                    #await channel.send(f'Сообщения были отправлено этому пользователю : {str(member)} ')
                    print("Отправил " + str(member))
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: Мой ds: RAINGM#1941

Comment: В дс запрос кинул) Спасибо за ответ